# How to disable a specific mailer on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

So I'm building an e-commerce platform using Shoppe 1.0.7.

Basically, I'd like my customers to get an e-mail with their order confirmation, their item listing, etc, so I built a mailer that does just that.

When I got it working, I found out Shoppe actually sends out its own confirmation e-mails, but these are way more generic and uninformative than mine are (also they're in English and I need mine in another language). So as it is, my customers are actually getting two e-mails when they make an order, which is obviously undesirable.

How do I disable Shoppe's mailer without disabling Shoppe as a whole (which I obviously need)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Shoppe but I can't see any configuration options around the mail on first glance. There are [four actions](https://github.com/tryshoppe/shoppe/blob/master/app/mailers/shoppe/order_mailer.rb) in the OrderMailer and they only seem to be used [here](https://github.com/tryshoppe/shoppe/blob/master/app/models/shoppe/order/actions.rb#L82) and [here](https://github.com/tryshoppe/shoppe/blob/master/app/models/shoppe/order/delivery.rb#L224). An option would be to open up the mailer class and redefine the methods.

```
module Shoppe
  class OrderMailer
    def received(order)
      true
    end
  end
end
```

It's not the best solution to have to monkey patch like this, a better option would be to use an action mailer [interceptor](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#intercepting-emails). Alternatively you could see if any issues for this have been raised on their repo and if not submit one, or a PR that would allow mail to be configured. Might be a nice feature to push upstream.

Comment: I'll definitely open the issue. I was just wondering if there was a general way to disable a mailer and it looks like the interceptor might work, I'll look into it.

Comment: Good stuff, if this solves your problem please accept it as it will help others who come across this in future.